# Splitting monolith data layer to microservices with no schema changes

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, microservices

I have a question about splitting the monolith (spring & hibernate) into micro-services. And especially I'm interested in the correct way of splitting the data layer.

I’ll take a simple example, the app manages users' accounts with those postal addresses, CRUD for account and addresses. DB schema is simple

[image]

Respectively there are the two related Hibernate entities
[image]

The goal is to split the app no two micro-services the account-service and the address-service but the **DB should remain the same one instance with no schema changes**.

I what fairly split the responsibility between the services and not pull unnecessary code.
So I updated my entities in a way that they have no mere dependencies between them.
[image]
Given that the database has not changed, are the new entities correct on point of view of Hibernate and microservices architecture patterns?

Answer (score 1):

Usually a microservice is entirely self-contained, including not sharing a database. That way a microservice actually **has** to call another service if it wants e.g. the address data. If they share a database then it doesn't really have to.

Assuming you want to share a database though: I'd personally just avoid joining the table in your application code. If you want to make it more difficult for your service to join the table then your approach works, but I'd also rename the int `account` to `accountId`, and remove the annotations `@JoinColumn` & `@ManyToOne`.

Comment: Sorry I've just forgotten to clean them up "@JoinColumn & @ManyToOne" from the example